# How do you control the order in which files appear in a GitHub Repository?

Tags: sorting, github, repository

In Github, Is there any manual way(like adding some config file, or something) to sort files in order of their date modified(not based on their lexicographical order), so that the files which has been modified latest appears at the first position & so on, in Github repository?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. You can just add the date it was last updated to the front of the file to achieve this thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option but on your local git clone...

Will use git-restore-mtime:
https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/git-restore-mtime/git-restore-mtime.1.en.html

We clone the repo as usual:
`https://github.com/idexo/idexo-sdk.git`

If we list the new folder we get:

```
ls -la

total 52
drwxrwxr-x  4 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 .git
drwxrwxr-x  3 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 .github
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   318 Nov  8 14:57 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu 11978 Nov  8 14:57 index.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   723 Nov  8 14:57 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   930 Nov  8 14:57 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   152 Nov  8 14:57 .prettierrc.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu  5015 Nov  8 14:57 README.md
```

we need to do:
`git restore-mtime`

Then date is as expected

```
ls -la

total 52
drwxrwxr-x  4 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Jun 14  2021 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 15:02 .git
drwxrwxr-x  3 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 .github
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   318 Jun 14  2021 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu 11978 Nov  4 17:33 index.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   723 Nov  8 11:41 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   930 Nov  8 11:41 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   152 Aug 18 10:04 .prettierrc.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu  5015 Nov  4 17:32 README.md
```

To sort by date-time we just do the `-t` flag:

```
ls -lat

total 52
drwxrwxr-x  8 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 15:02 .git
drwxrwxr-x  3 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 .github
drwxrwxr-x 23 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Nov  8 14:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   723 Nov  8 11:41 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   930 Nov  8 11:41 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu 11978 Nov  4 17:33 index.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu  5015 Nov  4 17:32 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   152 Aug 18 10:04 .prettierrc.js
drwxrwxr-x  4 heldersepu heldersepu  4096 Jun 14  2021 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 heldersepu heldersepu   318 Jun 14  2021 .gitignore
```